# how to reference a stub jar in android with ant commands in ubuntu

Tags: java, android, ant, classpath

I am building an android apk in jenkins using Ant. To create this apk I need to export a stub.jar file, but NOT package it into the apk itself. This is a stub jar so I cannot just put it under ./libs folder.   I have tried the following and none seems to make any imapct.

1) updated build.sh, I export the classpath of this jar file.
export CLASSPATH=$BUILD_PATH/stub.jar

Nothing, compiler still complaints unresolved symbol.

2) Added a compiler command
instead of the regular 'ant debug", i used 'ant debug -Djava.compiler.classpath=$BUILD_PATH/stub.jar'
Still nothing happens, unable to find symbol.

3) I even export this on Jenkins , same as (1).

4) I also updated ant.properties of this project, to overwrite the java class path:
java.classpath = =$BUILD_PATH/stub.jar

I also tried java.compiler.classpath, doesn't make any difference.

I am using openJDK 6, ant 1.8.2

what am I missing here? Thanks for your help.

Okay I have spent hours on google and still no clue.  It seems to me this might be a limitation with Ant tools in general.  So I am going to rewrite the build script in gradle instead, and hope this will resolve the issue. However if you are know the answer please still reply so I can get this up and running. I will need to learn gradle so will take me a while to fix this problem.

Comment: Okay, my colleague helped me to resolve this problem. It was all along a build error from my end. So the cleaniest way is do option (4). java.compiler.classpath=$BUILD_PATH/stub.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set in ant.properties:

```
java.compiler.classpath=<path_to_your_jar>/stub.jar
```

or on the command line:

```
ant debug -Djava.compiler.classpath=<path_to_your_jar>/stub.jar
```